# About port of entry - Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen

For my (Indian citizen) upcoming short vacation overseas in Europe, I have been granted  short term visa by the Swiss Embassy in Delhi. Due to some change in the plan, I have following specific questions:

1. Is it necessary to have Switzerland as the port of entry to Schengen States or I can enter at Paris or Amsterdam?
2. I am travelling to other Schengen States in Europe by road transport and enter and exit Zurich by road. This means there is no stamping on visa in Switzerland. Is this OK? I am however ensuring that my maximum stay is in Switzerland.
3. My port of exit may be Amsterdam.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I have Schengen visa, can I enter Schengen area from different country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22032/if-i-have-schengen-visa-can-i-enter-schengen-area-from-different-country)

Comment: @RodneyHawkins, I don't like the answer to the linked question because of how it covers the main destination issue.

Comment: If the *main destination* is still Switzerland, you can travel through any Schengen state. Be prepared to show plans of onward travel in Paris or Amsterdam, but that will be internal travel. That applies for internal flights as well as for road travel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Answer (score 1):

If you got a visa from the Swiss embassy, then Switzerland must be your main destination. As long as it's still true, it is OK if your port of entry or exit, or both, are not in Switzerland.

You say that you'll spend most days in Switzerland, so it qualifies as your main destination. Just make sure you have evidence supporting this, as you may be asked to show them when entering the Schengen area. In your case, I believe the best evidence would be hotel reservations in Switzerland. Train tickets can be good too.